# Identifiy this car from the 40's or 50s?

Tags: vehicle-identification

Not really the right place for this question I'm sure, but I saw this old rusty car on a bushwalk (in Australia) and wondered what it was. Anyone know?

[image: Rusty old car]

Comment: Ummm, whomever voted to close this as *primarily opinion based* needs to rethink what's an opinion. Just because *you* can not identify this vehicle, doesn't mean *someone else* cannot. No opinion needed, just some savvy Google skills (if I do say so myself) and an eye for detail. I can give you at least five points of reference in this picture which corresponds to my answer below.

Comment: Thanks for your answer which looks spot on. I did do a Google image search but gave up after a few pages.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

That appears to be a [Ford Prefect](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ford_Prefect):

[image]

( ... or what's left of it ... )

**EDIT:** To tell you what tipped the scales for me as to *why* this is a Ford Prefect (and at Josh Caswell's suggestion), I'll add the things I looked at which gave me this as my answer.

- Looking at the shape of the rear window. Curved at the back while straight, yet slanted forward on the leading edge.
- Drip rails coming from the front of the vehicle until just over (to the end) of the opening for the rear window.
- Shape of the rear fender.
- Rear fender being a separate piece from the body.
- Rolled body line just above the rear fender.
- Body line at the middle of the car (on the side), which extends from the front of car until almost the rear of the car, with a sloping fade to it at the end.

Comment: @JoshCaswell - While I basically agree with your sentiment, it doesn't make it off-topic or primarily opinion based. We have had other ID questions before which were well received (or at least were upvoted). I can really only think of three such questions (including this one) since I've joined. It's not like we get inundated with them.

Comment: Surely you can tell what year it was made from that photo too? :)

Comment: @John - It *must be* a '49. Only one it (*cough*) could be.